# How to output unknown number of items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

If I'm outputting rows of data to a CSV file with the CSV gem, but I have an unknown number of items for each row, stored in an array, how can I include all items?

For example, for the first row I have a fixed cell followed by X number items, which might be 2 in the first row but 20 in the second. If it was always 2 I would do:

```
CSV.open('file.csv', 'a') do |csv|
   csv << ["#{Some_text}","#{cell2}","#{cell3}"]
end
```

But how can I include more only when needed?

Comment: CSV files in general support the idea of missing data in rows. They'll output a series of commas, which mark the fields which are missing the data. I'm not sure how it will react when reading the new field lengths being appended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the `<<` method takes an array, you can construct as many columns as you want and pass them in using simple array math:

```
CSV.open('file.csv', 'a') do |csv|
  csv << [ 'Fixed cell' ] + [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  csv << [ 'Fixed cell' ] + [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
  csv << [ 'Fixed cell' ] + other_array
end
```

It's possible to combine several arrays into a singular array using `+`. There is no inherent restriction on the length of these arrays, and no requirement in CSV to have all rows have the same number of columns.

As a note, it's almost always redundant to say `"#{var}"` instead of simply `var`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
*cells = cell1,cell2,celln   # You can add as many as you need
CSV.open('file.csv', 'a') do |csv|
  csv << [ 'Fixed cell' ] + cells
end
```

The splat operator(*) might give you the flexibility you're looking for.

Regards,